# SQL Server service dependency not working

Tags: sql-server, windows-service, dependencies

I have an service that tries to connect to a MSSQL DB on startup, but when I start the computer it throws an error becouse it's not able to connect to the DB. This happens becouse the specific DB was not started by the MSSQL Service yet, even though my service has a dependecy set for the MSSQL Service.

What can I do? Any solutions?

I could add a delay to my service of let's say 5 minutes, but that would be the last solution I would use as it's not a proper one from my point of view. [image]

LE : Forgot to say, it must work on windows XP SP3, I've tried with auto-delay but it won't work.

Comment: A database =/= SQL server services. SQL server services is the overlaying service that runs the databases. It's like saying "My radio isn't on yet, but I started my car"... Well fine, turn on your radio then. Regardless, it sounds like your app is not designed to be run on start up, or at least not have the SQL server hosted on the same machine as the app... Not a problem to solve, simply start your app manually after reboot.

Comment: The MSSQL Server is on the same machine as the service I want to run and starting the app manually is not a solution, i have to do this automatically as people working on that station have very little knowledge or none at all about services/registry and other computer management problems, all they know is that is has to work.